# How to summarize "water bill" and "electricity bill" into a word?

Tags: word-request

In my country, China, people pay electricity and water bills monthly.

I'm writing some code (I'm talking about programming, but it doesn't matter if you know nothing about programming) about that, so I created two variables named `WaterBill` and `ElectricityBill` for the corresponding bills.

Now, I want to create a variable which can denote `WaterBill` or `ElectricityBill` both.

I know I could name it `Bill` (both `WaterBill` and `ElectricityBill` are bills, I know), but I wonder, is there a word which denotes the bill you receive on a regular time schedule -- especially for water bill or electricity bill --precisely?

Comment: Interestingly, in at least some parts of Canada, they say "hydro" to refer to the electrical utilities, so their electricity bill is already called a "hydro bill" (I think water usage is on a separate bill, though, so that's not an answer per se).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can say "a utility bill" that's used in both American and British English.

Among many senses, the word utility also means a public commodity or service such as electricity, water, telephone, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that traditionally **water** and **electricity** are supplied by two different utilities and not **bundled** together.

For example, when **gas** and **electricity** are supplied by the same company and the billing is **combined**, this might be refered to as a **power bill**.

**Water** and **trash removal** may be combined into a **services bill** (depending on specific situations).

**Utility bill** is more encompassing than your specific request.

Since you are asking about a variable name, you could use **power_elec_bill** which is descriptive (a good thing for variable names), or possibly **powater** if you want to combine power and water.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I think `UtilityBill` will be good. I think `powater_bill` is confusing.

Comment: After having to work with code full of variable names like 'crunt' and 'blid', I would definitely appreciate finding a variable called UtilityBill rather than trying to guess what you meant by powater.

Comment: `powater` would fail any code review I was a part of. Water, electricity, and gas bills would all be of the utility bill type.